# Midori Keeps Crashing - Or How to Download a File from the Internet if Midori Keeps Crashing

Tags: midori

[EDIT]: Here is how to do it:

Find the download link and wget it. If your downloading from Oracle they make you accept the licence agreement, and then give you the link. If you get a certificate error, add the `no-check-certificate` option to wget.

If you want the Oracle JDK8 for ARM, issue this statement:

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk8/archive/b99/binaries/jdk-8-ea-b99-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-17_jul_2013.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
```

[/EDIT]

I am attempting to download the JDK8 for Linux ARM (218.45MB file) from https://jdk8.java.net/download.html .

If I accept Oracle's agreement and get the link, I try this in WGET:

```
wget http://www.java.net/download/jdk8/archive/b99/binaries/jdk-8-ea-b99-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-17_jul_2013.tar.gz
```

and receive the following error:

```
Connecting to www.java.net (www.java.net)|209.189.227.38|:443... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of `www.java.net' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of `www.java.net' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

The first time I tried to download it, it actually got about 99% of the way through before Midori crashed. The MD5 didn't match.

Now every time I try it appears to be getting worse, now its crashing at less than a third of the way there. I've tried about 10 times.

Even when I initially got my RPi and had no programs running, Midori seemed to crash a lot.

How can I get around this?

With Midori open, my `free -h` says 16M free in memory, 31M free in buffers/cache. With Midori closed, my `free -h` says 7M in memory, 114M in buffers/cache.

Comment: Try adding --no-check-certificate to the wget command; My pi can download it.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Sweet it is downloading I'll give you the answer as soon as it completes. Thank you for this answer and the MD5!

Comment: No problem, glad they helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why Midori has as much trouble as it does, but I managed to grab the url for you:

```
http://www.java.net/download/jdk8/archive/b99/binaries/jdk-8-ea-b99-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-17_jul_2013.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hey @Jacobm001, I tried that route earlier with `wget` and I receive the error listed in my edit above. Do you know a way around that? Thanks

Comment: Try adding: --no-check-certificate